# Why is this change emitted using Rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm a little bit confused as why the following snipped **works** as *expected*.
The idea of this service is to have a list of strings where if you add a string, it is removed 5 seconds later. Rxjs is used here:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorService {

  private errors: Array<string> = [];
  private emitErrorsChanged = new Subject<any>();
  public emitErrorsChanged$ = this.emitErrorsChanged.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this.emitErrorsChanged$.delay(5000).subscribe(
      () => {
        if (this.errors.length > 0) {
          this.errors.shift();
        }
      }
    );
  }

  public emitErrorChange(error: string) {
    this.errors.push(`${error}`);
    this.emitErrorsChanged.next(this.errors);
  }
}
```

An error component is subscribed to this service `errorService.emitErrorsChanged$.subscribe(...)` and shows the strings in a list. Other components/services add strings by `this.errorService.emitErrorChange(error.message)`.

> My question is: why are the removed errors (5s) emitted to the error component? The errors are just removed from the list `this.errors.shift();` but the change is not emitted by `this.emitErrorsChanged.next(this.errors);`

Comment: Why do you think the change is emitted anywhere? If you iterate `errors` in a template it will be updated automatically thanks to the change detection.

Comment: When I see these type of "magic" actions in Angular, often I find it is do to Angular binding something by _name convention_.  Try renaming your methods/fields and see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: @martin I do not iterate over the services `errors` list in my component. The component holds it's own 'errors' list which is set by    `errorService.emitErrorsChanged$.subscribe(errors => this.errors = errors );`.

Comment: If i think about it... do i just pass a reference of the errors list from my service to my component with `this.emitErrorsChanged.next(this.errors);`, and in the end the errors displayed, are actually binding to the list from the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior occurs because you are passing reference to your object (list in this case). The changes made by `this.errors.shift();` are not emitted, but I guess you can see current state of `this.errors` thanks to Angular's change detection. I have prepared a [demo (click)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vWVjLZ?editors=1010) so you can see that the object reference is passed in your case - what means that the list in subscription is the exactly same `array` list. To prevent it you can pass a copy of your list, e.g. using spread operator like in [this example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVJYNa?editors=1010):

```
this.emitErrorsChanged.next([...this.errors]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation of my assumption! Looking at how JavaScript always passes a reference for Objects/Arrays it kinda makes sense if you look at it. I think rxjs broke my head here, i was under the impression that `.next(...)` always passes a value to every subscriber.